# Hardcoding Parameters vs. loading from a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, coding-style, c++-cli

I am working on a motion control system, and will have at least 5 motors, each with parameters such as "gearbox ratio", "ticks per rev" "Kp", "Ki", "Kd", etc. that will be referenced upon construction of instances of the motors.

My question to StackOverflow is how should I organize these numbers? I know this is likely a preferential thing, but being new to coding I figure I could get some good opinions from you.

The three approaches I immediately see are as follows:

1. Write in the call to the constructor, either via variables or numbers-- PROS: limited coding, could be implemented in a way that it's easy to change, but possibly harder than #define's
2. Use #define's to accomplish similar to above -- PROS: least coding, easy to change (assuming you want to look at the source code)
3. Load a file (possibly named "motorparameters.txt") and load the parameters into an array and populate from that array. If I really wanted to I could add a GUI approach to changing this file rather than manual. -- PROS:easiest to change without diving into source code.

These parameters could change over time, and while there are other coders at the company, I would like to leave it in a way that's easy to configure. Do any of you see a particular benefit of #define vs. variables? I have a "constants.h" file already that I could easily add the #defines to, or I could add variables near the call to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like the thing to do is:

- Write a flexible motor class, that can handle any values (within reason), even though there are only 5 different sets of values you currently care about.
- Define a component that returns the "right" values for the 5 motors in your system (or that constructs the 5 motors for your system using the "right values")
- Initially implement that component to use some hard-coded values out of a header file
- Retain the option to replace that component in future with an implementation of the same API, but that reads values out of a resource file, text file, XML file, GUI interaction with the user, off the internet, by making queries to the hardware to find out what motors it thinks it has, whatever.

I say this on the basis that you minimize expected effort by putting in a point of customizability where you suspect you'll want one (to prevent a lot of work when you change it later), but implement using the simplest thing that satisfies your current certain requirements.

Some people might say that it's not actually worth doing the typing (a) to define the component, better just to construct 5 motors in `main()` (b) to use constants from a header file, better just to type numeric literals in `main()`. The (b) people are widely despised as peddlers of "magic constants" (which doesn't mean they're *necessarily* wrong about relative total programming time by implementer and future maintainers, they just probably are) and the (a) people divide opinion. I tend to figure that defining this kind of thing takes a few minutes, so I don't really care whether it's worth it or not. Loading the values out of a file involves specifying a file format that I might regret as soon as I encounter a *real* reason to customize, so personally I can't be bothered with that until the requirement arises.

Comment: Thank you for a solid complete solution. I think this is the approach I will take. A co-worker suggested using #defines for default values, and saving updates into a registry file. I will look into this more, and I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 4):

There's a principle know as [YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) which says do the simplest thing first, then change it when (if) your requirements expand.

Comment: While I like this approach, I think the below answer is more complete, and what I have decided to do after talking with a few colleagues, thank you for your help!

Comment: @fooOnYou, programming is all about making a series of informed tradeoffs once you get past anything trivial. Most people don't even consider that they have choices, they just do the first thing that comes to mind. I'm sure you're doing the right thing. One more principle I didn't include in my answer: programs are read many more times than they're written, so do the thing that makes the program easiest to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to separate the portions of your code that will change from those that won't.  The more likely something is to change, the more you need to make it easy to change.

If you're building a commercial app where hundreds or thousands of users will use many different motors, it might make sense to code up a UI and store the data in a config file.

If this is development code and these parameters are unlikely to change, then stuffing them into #defines in your constants.h file is probably the way to go.

Comment: This is very early development code, we may get hundreds of customers some day, but in the mean time we need to make a working product..! I think I will go the #define route then looking into saving to the registry. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 is a great option if you don't have security or IP concerns.  Anytime you or someone else touches your code, you introduce the possibility of regressions.  By keeping your parameters in a text file, not only are you making life easier on yourself, you're also reducing the scope of possible errors down the road.

Comment: I decided against this because I didn't want to manage a file. If I do choose to save externally eventually, I am likely to look into saving to the registry to avoid having to manage the file. Thanks!